# Python3 convert normal string to bytestring

Tags: python, string, replace, type-conversion, byte

I have the following string that represents bytes separated byte a comma:

`"0xe7,0xcd,0xb0,0xa2"`

**However**

I am trying to convert the normal string into a byte string:

`b"\xe7\xcd\xb0\xa2"`

how would i do that using python?, i think maybe using replace but how would i make it a byte string?

Comment: `bytes.fromhex(s.replace("0x", "").replace(",", ""))` a bit weird, but it works. You can also use generator: `bytes(int(i, 16) for i in s.split(","))`.